# Render all records with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firebase-realtime-database

I want to render all json db entries onto browser but looks like it only fetches last entry.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Candidate Lookup Table </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="bigTextEvaluationStudents"></h1>
       <table class="table" id="table1" >
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>company </th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>message </th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th> phone </th>
    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </body>
 </table>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" 
  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: ""
  
  };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 var database = firebase.database();
 var leadsRef = database.ref('messages');
 leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
 var childData = childSnapshot.val();
 var obj = JSON.stringify(childData);
 $(function(){
  var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(childData));
  var html = '<table border="1">';
  console.log(obj);
  $.each(jsonObj, function(key, value){
   html += '<tr>';
   html += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
   html += '</tr>'; });
   html += '</table>';
   $('div').html(html);
            });   
  });
 });
        
 </script>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am seeing only one entry in output while there are three in the database.

This is the data I see while there are four entries in the database. How do I fetch all entries? The data from firebase does not pass any json validator.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @kusuma will work but it can be improved. First when you are apending html don't use generic selector like `div` better to go with an id or a class name. Another improvement is how your are appending the data, don't just change the entire div, it will mess up your UI display. Check the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Candidate Lookup Table </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="bigTextEvaluationStudents"></h1>
       <table class="table" id="table1" >
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>company </th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>message </th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th> phone </th>
    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='push_content'>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" 
  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAvSuAXxizKOPEB6QWxjPb0acN2t6l2oU8",
  authDomain: "jobrecuiters-9552a.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://jobrecuiters-9552a.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "jobrecuiters-9552a",
  storageBucket: "jobrecuiters-9552a.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "846593931464"
  
  };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 var database = firebase.database();
 var leadsRef = database.ref('messages');
 leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
 var childData = childSnapshot.val();
 var obj = JSON.stringify(childData);
 $(function(){
  var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(childData));
  var html = '';
  console.log(obj);
  $.each(jsonObj, function(key, value){
   html += '<tr>';
   html += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
   html += '</tr>'; });
   
   $('#push_content').append(html);
            });   
  });
 });
        
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: This code is just an improved version of yours, you have some issue with the configuration which the above code won't fix. Please check and fix it
 AND 
 don't post sensitive information like `apiKey` in a public post**

Comment: I agree with @Kuru for not using generic selector while making changes to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an HTML  with in a loop using .html(). This would overwrite the previous element.

`$('div').html(html);`

You have to use .append() method to append new elements.

```
$('div').append(html);
```